# XQuery search multiple files using webdav ftp

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I want to use xquery to search all the files I have in the "xml" folder. The problem is that the folder is on my webdav ftp oracle server and I can not use the collection () function in the "xml" folder but I can use the doc () function. When using the collection () function, an error appears.

XML Code

```
let $organization_file := collection("XML/?select*.xml")
```

Message error: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.

Thank you

Comment: Much of the detail of the collection() function depends on which XQuery processor you are using, so you really need to tell us!

Comment: The message rather suggests to me that a file has been successfully read and its contents are decipherable as XML but it's not well-formed.